# Color display error while applying a mask

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to filter an image in OpenCV (with Python) but I get a *blue region instead of black* after the application of a mask.

Shortly, the code changes the color space of the image from BGR to LAB, then creates a mask with the function `cv2.inRange` and reverses it with `cv2.bitwise_not`. After that, the mask gets applied with the function `cv2.bitwise_and`. Here are the original and filtered frame:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pGym.png]

In the beginning, I thought that could be a problem between the BGR/RGB image representation but blue region excluded, the colors of the image are correct.

Here is the code:

```py
# Parameter "frame": BGR image.
# Parameter "min": min LAB val.
# Parameter "max": max LAB val.
# Return filtered frame in BGR.
def applyFilter(frame, min, max):

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

    mask = cv2.inRange(frame, min, max)
    mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

    filtered_frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    return cv2.cvtColor(filtered_frame, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
```

Comment: what library you used to show result image?

Comment: I simply use cv2.imshow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAB colorspace has 3 channels, `L` which goes from 0-100%, `a` which goes from -128 to 128 and `b` which goes from -128 to 128. OpenCV values in LAB for a uint8 image are as follows:

[image]

Your problem is that in OpenCV the value `(0,0,0`) in LAB is in reality `(0, -128, -128)` which one can look in an online [colorpicker](http://colorizer.org/) and see that is blue.

When you apply the mask, what is not in the mask stays "black"(0,0,0) and once it is converted from LAB to BGR it is then blue. If the idea is to leave what is not selected in black you have 2 solutions:

1) apply the mask to the original image

2) convert the `0,0,0` pixels to `0,128,128`

For 1) the code will be like this:

```
# Parameter "frame": BGR image.
# Parameter "min": min LAB val.
# Parameter "max": max LAB val.
# Return filtered frame in BGR.
def applyFilter(frame, min, max):

    tempFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

    mask = cv2.inRange(tempFrame, min, max)
    mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

    filtered_frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    return filtered_frame
```